# How to run different Maven goals on source changes vs updated snapshot dependencies

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins + Maven plugin question:  I want Jenkins to run "mvn test" when a build is triggered by a new version of a snapshot dependency, but "mvn deploy" when a build is triggered by SCM changes.  I can't figure out how to do this.

Backstory:  we have a homegrown ant + ivy + jenkins build system, and I'm trying to figure out how practical it would be to migrate to Maven.  General setup:

- we have several dozen Java projects, with fairly complex dependency chains between them (almost all projects depend on a couple of generic libraries which are under active development)
- all projects deploy as snapshot builds to an ivy repository.  All projects which depend on on internal projects depend on the current snapshot version of that project.
- when any project has source changes, jenkins picks up the SCM change and deploys a new snapshot version.
- when an upstream project builds and deploys a new snapshot, Jenkins runs tests on all downstream projects but does NOT deploy.  This is is done via dark Ant magic.

I'm having a hard time replicating the last point using Jenkin's maven plugin.  We can't deploy new snapshots on every build because developers would spend most of their day downloading new snapshot versions (each project builds dozens of times a day, since some upstream projects are under very active development.)

Any thoughts on how to configure Jenkins' maven plugin to run different goals on SCM changes vs dependency changes?

Answer (score 0):

What about just creating two separate Jenkins jobs - for testing and for deployment?

Comment: I've thought about that, but it seems like it would introduce a number of problems.  Biggest one is, we won't have a single view on jenkins for project health (sometimes one build will be broken, sometimes the other).  When looking at the project failures, we wouldn't be sure if we're even seeing failures which reflect the current project code, if it was triggered by dependency changes rather than code changes...

Answer (score 0):

To close the circle on this question a few years later--

It turns out that re-downloading jars is not nearly as big a problem as I thought it would be.  Usually developers just use intellij, in which case they don't have to resolve snapshots at all, or use -o for offline mode unless they really need to deploy with the latest jars.  So not a lot of time is being wasted on downloading after all.

So I still have no idea how to do this, but it's probably not worth trying to figure it out.